# Software Center not opening -- Keyerror: 'countrycode'

Tags: software-center

after some kde-librieries updates (from official repos) I'm unable to open the Software Center.

Here's the terminal output:

```
francesco@francesco-HP-Workstation:~$ software-center
2014-06-18 14:53:54,382 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 130, in <module>
    app = SoftwareCenterAppGtk3(options, args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 397, in __init__
    self.icons)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/installedpane.py", line 95, in __init__
    CategoriesParser.__init__(self, db)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/categories.py", line 251, in __init__
    self._build_string_template_dict()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/categories.py", line 303, in _build_string_template_dict
    region = "%s" % get_region_cached()["countrycode"]
KeyError: 'countrycode'
```

and the log generated:

```
2014-06-18 14:53:54,382 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
```

Any Ideas?

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did is to change region.get_region_cached() (`sudo vi /usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/region.py`) as follows:

```
def get_region_cached():
    global my_region
    if my_region is None:
        rd = RegionDiscover()
        my_region = rd.get_region()
    my_region.setdefault('countrycode','BG')
    return my_region
```

my change is the line:

```
my_region.setdefault('countrycode','BG')
```

where "BG" is the region code for my country.

I know that this doesn't resolve the problem, but at least I can use software center now.

Comment: Thank you very much! The workaround works for me to. Any Idea which is the best way to report the bug?