# Ubuntu software center not opening error "countrycode"

Tags: software-center

I have an error which is exactly the same with this one [Software Center not opening -- Keyerror: 'countrycode'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485022/software-center-not-opening-keyerror-countrycode)
I'm not sure whether it is because I chose to download update in the system setting from an US server while I'm living in malaysia. I have installed Ubuntu for 1 week and the software center was working fine until yesterday ( I've changed the server the first day I install). When I try to solve using the method provided by that post, I realized that I don't have the permission so I can't save after editing it. So what should I do now ?

Comment: " I realized that I don't have the permission so I can't save after editing it" You need to use "sudo". I changed the original question to make that clear. Basically this a dupe to what you link to).

Comment: I don't know how to use terminal to open the file so I just locate the file, open and edit it with geany

Answer (score 0):

Change file region.get_region_cached() (sudo vi /usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/region.py) as follows:

def get_region_cached():
    global my_region
    if my_region is None:
        rd = RegionDiscover()
        my_region = rd.get_region()
    my_region.setdefault('countrycode','BG')
    return my_region

change is only in the line:

my_region.setdefault('countrycode','BG')

where "BG" is the region code for my country.

I know that this doesn't resolve the problem, but at least I can use software center now.

using command line..